# How to handle PartialView with different model than parent View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I'm using VS2012 RC with MVC4, bot for all intents and purposes let's pretend it's MVC3. I would like to know what the standard best practice(s) is on how to handle PartialViews with a form that uses a different model than the parent View.

For example, here is a view that displays a table of all the available Roles and also has a form that allows the user to add more roles.

Main View - Roles.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<RobotDog.Models.RoleModel>

<table>
    @foreach(var role in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td class="roleRow">@role.Role</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<div class="modal hide">
    @Html.Partial("_AddRolePartial")
</div>
```

_AddRolePartial.cshtml

```
@model RobotDog.Models.RoleModel

@using(Html.BeginForm("AddRole","Admin", FormMethod.Post)) {
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Role, new { @class = "input-xlarge", @placeholder = "Role"})
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large"/>
}
```

Model:

```
public class RoleModel {
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Role")]
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

Controller for View:

```
public ActionResult Roles() {
    var model = from r in System.Web.Security.Roles.GetAllRoles()
                select new RoleModel {Role = r};
    return View(model);
}
```

Controller for PartialView:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddRole(RoleModel model) {
    try {
        System.Web.Security.Roles.CreateRole(model.Role);
        RedirectToAction("Roles");
    } catch(Exception) {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Role creation unsuccessful.");
    }

    return ????; // not sure how to pass ModelState back to partialView
}
```

I thought about creating a ViewModel that held `RoleModel` and `IEnumerable<RoleModel>` but it seems like there would be a more stream lined way to accomplish what I wanted without having to create a ViewModel everytime I wanted to use this PartialView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking how to pass a RoleModel to the add RoleModel modal popup.  Since you are creating a new Role, I am assuming you are needing an empty model.  You can either pass it in like below:

```
<div class="modal hide">
    @Html.Partial("_AddRolePartial", new RoleModel())
</div>
```

Or just do a `@Html.RenderAction("AddRole")` with the supporing GET method of the controller to support populating the item.

```
public ActionResult AddRole() {
    var model = new RoleModel();
    //populate with any items needed for the Add Role Model View
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Yes but this is only half of the solution. When I submit the form to the AddRole controller how do I send back the `ModelState` to the form when an exception occurs?

Comment: You are really faced with only two options in that instance.  You either need to use an AJAX request which will only update the part of the page associated with the adding of a role or you will need to include to update your ViewModel to include a list of roles and a empty Role ViewModel.  I would recommend AJAX or else you will be (maybe) having to requery your roles over and over when you have to send back an error.  Using AJAX, you can easily return model errors and even append the newly created role to the existing list.

Comment: So my controller would return `JsonResult` and I would handle reloading the page on the client side if the submit was successful?

Comment: That could be one way of doing it - sure.  In our MVC projects, we have like a AjaxResultViewModel that we return as JSON (it has properties like successful, message, target, content) that we can have a generic JQuery handler parse to determine what to do next.  if(!data.successful){showError(data.Message)} for instance

Comment: Tommy, would you mind updating your answer to reflect the comments. I just want the answer to my question to be evident without having to scroll through all the comments. Thank you sir :)

Answer (score 0):

How about the form post is changed to an ajax form post with a target update partial id being the `div` which you will add to the parent view (effectively surrounding Roles.cshtml).

Add a new action `public ActionResult _Roles()` which will `return PartialView("Roles", model)`

Next, in the Post Action, `Return RedirectToAction(...Roles Partial Action ...)` at the end and remove RedirectToAction("Roles") in the `try`.

Comment: This sounds like an interesting solution. I don't understand the point of the surrounding div. Would you mind elaborating? Some example code perhaps?

Comment: You need a container so the result of the ajax in loading _Roles can be placed within it. I mistakenly suggested the container be in Roles.cshtml. The container should be in the parent view. I have adjusted my answer. Will try to work with you on this.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't like using Partial views with forms, because Partial Views do not render submodels correctly (ie, they don't take into account the hierarchy of the model).

This is why Display and EditorTemplates exist.  They work well for rendering specific data types.

However, in your case, since your view doesn't have any forms of its own, and the end result is just a single item of the collection of your parent model, then a Partial View is actually a better approach simply because you CAN pass a different model to it than the views uses.

As others have pointed out, you can easily pass an empty model to the partial as the second parameter.  I don't like newing up new objects in the view, but it doesn't look like there's a lot of choice there, as the alternatives would be pretty messy.